# While Running PHP Script for DynammoDB on AWS it gives 500 Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

This is the script I am using online on AWS server:

```
<?php

require './awsPackage/aws-autoloader.php';
use \Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;

$tableName = "table_name";

$ddb = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'region'   => 'us-west-2',
    'version'  => 'latest',
    'credentials' => array('key' => '<my_key>',
    'secret' => '<my_secret_key>'))); // EC2 role security

    try {
        $result = $ddb->describeTable(array(
            "TableName" => $tableName
        ));
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
        // if this exception is thrown, the table doesn't exist
        return false;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";

    if ($tableName == $result['Table']['TableName'])
        {
            echo $result['Table']['TableName'].": ".$result['Table']['TableStatus'];
        }

    else
        {
            echo $tableName." INACTIVE";
        }

?>
```

I am using this code to check whether the table provided exists in DynammoDB on online AWS server.

This code works fine on windows after setting up a local server.

But when I make this code online. It loads the page and then gives an error of 500. What might be the reason?

This is the Error Log:

`[Wed Mar 21 18:54:19.043570 2018] [:error] [pid 2831] [client 49.35.89.185:1410] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.' in /var/www/html/test/awsPackage/Aws/Api/DateTimeResult.php:19\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/test/awsPackage/Aws/Api/DateTimeResult.php(19): DateTime->__construct('2018-03-21T12:4...')\n#1 /var/www/html/test/awsPackage/Aws/Api/Parser/JsonParser.php(49): Aws\\Api\\DateTimeResult::fromEpoch(1521636246.401)\n#2 /var/www/html/test/awsPackage/Aws/Api/Parser/JsonParser.php(24): Aws\\Api\\Parser\\JsonParser->parse(Object(Aws\\Api\\TimestampShape), 1521636246.401)\n#3 /var/www/html/test/awsPackage/Aws/Api/Parser/JsonParser.php(24): Aws\\Api\\Parser\\JsonParser->parse(Object(Aws\\Api\\Struct in /var/www/html/test/awsPackage/Aws/Api/DateTimeResult.php on line 19`

Comment: Look at the web server error log 500 errors normally mean a catastrophic PHP error

Comment: where can i find that log?

Comment: I would check the AWS documentation

Comment: ok. Thanks, I got it I was in `var/log/httpd/`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've updated the question with the error LOG. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Set the default timezone in your php.ini

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please add your comments as an answer so that I can mark it :)

Comment: Answer added, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the php.ini file contains a valid `date.timezone`

Something like this for example

```
date.timezone = "UTC"
```

Or check the list of valid [timezones](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, It is important to always have a data.timezone value set. Otherwise, with this value undefined, PHP will: throw errors (May be Errors turned off in your local -but not in live)
You can set it via code - Run Time

```
ini_set("date.timezone", "America/New_York");
```